# Sitecore SocialConnect 1.3: programmatically retrieve user details

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I've implemented SocialConnect Module for Sitecore. I am able to log in using facebook login button.

But, the sitecore database (Core database and user & profile tables) are not updated with user details.

I'm unable to get user's profile information programmatically.

Can anyone guide on me how to achieve it?

Adding more details to it:

Each time I load the page, it throws an exception of type Sitecore.Social.Core.Exception.SocialException.

Error is : {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: accessToken"}

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Thanks Shriroop for correcting it. I'm using version Sitecore 7.0

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.dansolovay.com/2012/09/a-look-at-sitecore-social-connected.html) helped me a lot. From the error it looks like the authtoken was not captured properly?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Did you try programmatically looping through the user profile custom properties?
Please look into this blog as well: [Social Connected with Sitecore (Facebook) 2: Access facebook information](http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/social-connected-with-sitecore-facebook-2-access-facebook-information/)